# use dynamic value in a config file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i have config file for payments, i should use dynamic value (that is loading from db) for `merchant-id` key:

in `AppServiceProvider` in `boot` method 
i write this

```
 $zarinpal = PaymentConfig::where('slug', 'zarinpal')->first();

        config()->set(['app.zarinpal' => ['merchant' => $zarinpal->merchant ?? 0]]);
```

but `config('app.zarinpal')["merchant"]` value is null there... how can i fix this issue?

```
return [

    //-------------------------------
    // Timezone for insert dates in database
    // If you want Gateway not set timezone, just leave it empty
    //--------------------------------
    'timezone' => 'Asia/Tehran',

    //--------------------------------
    // Zarinpal gateway
    //--------------------------------
    'zarinpal' => [
        'merchant-id'  => config('app.zarinpal')["merchant"],//'xx',
        'type'         => 'zarin-gate',             // Types: [zarin-gate || normal]
        'callback-url' => '/',
        'server'       => 'germany',                // Servers: [germany || iran || test]
        'email'        => 'email@gmail.com',
        'mobile'       => '09xxxxxxxxx',
        'description'  => 'description',
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use helper functions except [env()](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-env) inside config files in Laravel because those files are loaded and cached **way before**  `AppServiceProvider` in the pipeline and therefor you get `null`

If you want to get something from the database by a simple global function call, make your own

For example

`app/Helpers.php`

```php
<?php

// Name it however you want
function getMerchant()
{
  $zarinpal = PaymentConfig::where('slug', 'zarinpal')->first();
  return $zarinpal
}
```

Load it to the composer class-map via `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Helpers.php"
        ]
    },
```

Now you can call `getMerchant()` anywhere in your code (except config) and get the record out of the database

---

Insert through the helper using dot notation

```php
config(['app.zarinpal.merchant' => $zarinpal->merchant ?? 0]);
```

And access it like so

```php
config('app.zarinpal.merchant');
```

Note that this is a bad design decision, you should make a global helper function instead because config files load before anything else

Comment: when i dd() value of dd(config('app.zarinpal.merchant')); in  related config file it return null

Comment: but i want use it in config.. in a config file some key should load from database

Comment: You can not do that! it's impossible, helper functions do the same thing so why not that? and it's even shorter

Comment: ```config(['app.zarinpal.merchant' => $zarinpal->merchant ?? 0]);
```
this code override  merchant key that is availble in zarinpal config file ???

Comment: No, this code runs **BEFORE** `AppServiceProvider` and hence you get null